# Can I pass null as an argument to as3 signals?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a signal like this:

```
public var e_collision:Signal = new Signal(GameObj);
```

When the object collides with another, I pass the other object as the argument.

But if the object collides with a wall, the wall is not a `GameObj`, I would like to know, can I pass `null` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had time to test, result: I can pass null as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

http://www.peterelst.com/blog/2010/01/22/as3-signals-the-best-thing-since-sliced-bread/

Comment: I am asking if the as3 signals checks if the object is not null.